# Hosting a blog on Google Cloud could help in SEO ranking?

Tags: web-hosting, google-ranking, cloud-hosting

We usually host our blogs on shared hosting providers. These service providers use same shared space and IP for hundreds of blogs and websites.

Are there any chances that Google considers such shared IPs a less valuable? Instead they give more importance to sites and blogs hosted on Google Cloud services, they consider it as one of the secret ranking factors and assign more favor in SEO rankings? I am not able to find any supporting documents on this argument.

However, I recall that Google+ was not becoming as popular as FB so Google started considering Google+ profile as one of the ranking factors.

So could similar logic applicable for Google Cloud Hosting? Not sure exactly.

Comment: First, Google+ was never a ranking factor. It was a trust factor simply because the person is vetted to some level whereas with any other social media, it is not. Full stop. Second, dedicated IP versus shared IP has not been a factor for a fairly long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's algorithm is evolving passed what any one person could understand. That even includes the very Google engineers themselves who have developed the algorithm.

What we do know is that various parts of the Google algorithm have been instructed to do various tasks to improve Google's usage rate.

For instance, Youtube's algorithm has been built around the concept of "increase watch time". So the recommended videos that Youtube provides to you have been shown to you because it thinks it will keep you on the Youtube Platform longer.

I imagine there is a high likelihood that there are algorithms in place to increase Google Cloud usage, to increase Adsense clicks, etc etc. As a result, it's quite possible that what you're suspecting may be true. And if it's not an additional ranking signal now, it could be in the future. Ultimately, using Google Cloud probably doesn't have much downside (if the servers work properly). But there is a hidden upside that may or may not exist.

Comment: Thanks!! This is really helpful. I do understand that right now there isn’t any specific ranking signal, but anything could happen in future.

Answer (score 1):

Hosting on Google won't affect your ranking, but hosting on low-class company can affect your ranking, because, Google has recently announced its core algorithm update that, a website with low speed will be penalized or rank very slow. We all know that Google always works to provide quality things to its users and show them highly relevant results with good quality.

First of all, Now all the small or large websites are moving their sites from shared to the cloud, because due to having multiple websites in 1 server affects your website loading time and also bounce rate. Its due to slow server response.

I will suggest you check your site loading time with Google site speed test tool and fix all the changes. Move your website or blog to cloud hosting, so that, you will have only your website hosted on 1 server with high bandwidth and response rate.

I also own a blog and Magento store which is hosted by Cloudways and I am using GCE for it. You can try them and check site loading time after migrating to their managed platform.

Answer (score 0):

Google indexes sites all the same. They appear to give the same importance to all sites since you can not request crawling on demand (and even in some cases where you might you need to wait days for it ti be accepted [if it even is accepted at all]). All I see would be a benefit is that if you don't know/want to bother with setting up an advanced blog it might be easier for you to use a 5 or so click shell script or something to set up.

Comment: Not all sites are equally well indexed in Google.   Even if you are trying to add "based on hosting" to that, hosting does matter.   Speed and geographic location of a site can have dramatic impact on indexing and ranking in Google.

Answer (score -3):

It will speed up your website, and blog posts and images will load faster.

Comment: This was flagged as a low quality answer. Can you elaborate? For example, How does what you say increase search performance?

Comment: You could also link to articles or documentation that support your position.   Please edit your answer to improve it.